# Solution Description Maximum Length in Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm

I have been using the description field in a solution to keep track of changes each versions. And now I encounter a limitation that the field only allows 2000 characters.

Is there any way to expand the field maximum length? Or is there another way for me to note changes?

UPDATED: While I am marking Henk van Boeijen's suggestion the answer, I choose to trim down the oldest version note to make room for new one in the description field. I don't need to save too old note.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

2,000 characters is the maximum length. Period.

However you can add a **configuration page** to your solution. This is an HTML web resource file. You could use this HTML file to hold your version history. This way you are not limited to a fixed size at all. (And you can also add some markup when needed.)

> **NOTE**
>
> The description field's content is stored in the developer's language. This means that on multi language enabled organizations users (mostly administrators) having another language setting may not see the correct version description.
>
> Bottom line: the solution's description field is not intended for holding version information.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the Notes entity for tracking large description strings or logs of custom workflows/plugins that do bulk jobs.

I simply create a .txt file with the string contents, and attach it against the desired entity. This way you can store a quite a large string of up to 5 Mb big (this can also be increased). Depending on your desired logic you can add new txt files or simply update the existing one you created.